# Referencing to an Array inside of Object

Tags: json, vega-lite

There is following data Object:

```json
{
  "station": {
    "id": {"name": "SNK"},
    "position": {"lat":0.00,"lon":0.00}
  },
  "datagram": [
    {
      "date": {"iso-8601": "1966-01-12"},
      "air": {
        "temp": {"mean": -17.8}
      },
      "precip": {"1d": 1}
    }
  ]
}
```

Data in question are inside of "datagram" array, and they are:

- date.iso-8601,
- air.temp.mean

So, is needed to indicate directly Array as data source.

I tried Transform with Calculate to create a new 'd' array:
(spec fragment)

```js
data: {
  url: 'http://...',
  format: {type: 'json'}
},
transform: [
  {calculate: "datum.datagram", "as": "d"}
],
encoding: {
  x: {type: 'temporal', field: 'd.date.iso_date_time', title: 'Date'},
  y: {type: 'quantitative', field: 'd.air.temp.mean', title: '[°C]'}
}
```

It not work:

```
vega@5.22.1:1 WARN Infinite extent for field "d.date.iso_date_time": [Infinity, -Infinity]
```

The Question is: How in general I should deal, in vanilla Vega-Lite, with extracting data table from an object?

Complete spec:

```js
{
$schema: 'https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json',
description: '',
width: 'container',
  data: {
      url:'',
      format: {type: 'json'}
  },
  transform: [
    {calculate: "datum.datagram", "as": "d"}
  ],
  mark: 'circle',
  encoding: {
     x: {type: 'temporal', field: 'd.time.iso_date_time', title: 'Date'},
     y: {type: 'quantitative', field: 'd.air.temp.mean', title: '[°C]'}
  }
};
```

[EDIT]

#### Long Term Vanilla JS Solution

In this case, One can directly assign data Array outside the Vega-Lite, without invoking Calculate and Flattening:

```
 var vegaLiteSpec = {
   $schema: 'https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json',
   // define data as with no values at all:
   data: {values: []},
   // ...here is the rest of configuration...
 };


 fetch('https://...')
   .then(res => res.json())
   .then((out) => {
     vegaLiteSpec.data.values = out.datagram;
     vegaEmbed('#div-chartElement', vegaLiteSpec);
   })
   .catch(err => {
     throw err
   });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {
        "station": {"id": {"name": "SNK"}, "position": {"lat": 0, "lon": 0}},
        "datagram": [
          {
            "date": {"iso-8601": "1966-01-12"},
            "air": {"temp": {"mean": -17.8}},
            "precip": {"1d": 1}
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "transform": [
    {"calculate": "datum.datagram", "as": "d"},
    {"flatten": ["d"]},
    {"calculate": "datum.d.date['iso-8601']", "as": "x"},
      {"calculate": "datum.d.air.temp.mean", "as": "y"}
  ],
  "mark": "point",
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "x", "type": "ordinal"},
    "y": {"field": "y", "type": "quantitative"}
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank You!
So, basically we need to call two operations together:   
`
transform: [
  {flatten: 'datum.dataogram', as: 'd'},
  {flatten: ['d']}
]
`
And then call data:    
`
encoding: {
  x: {field: 'd.date.iso-8601', type: 'temporal'},
  y: {field: 'd.air.temp.mean', type: 'quantitative'}
}
`

Comment: The flatten is because your had an array. If you don't have an array, no need to flatten. You might have issues with type temporal as the date will need to be parsed correctly but that is a separate topic.